# how come my get reqest to server.js returns the actual file on ionic - cloud 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, server, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to send a get request to my server.js and have it return "get request recieved"

I'm also using ionic

However when I do the get request the data that is returned is the actual contents of the file

app.js: (client side)

```
$http.get('/myApp/index.js')
          .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                alert("YES "+ data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                alert("rip "+ data);
            });
```

index.js (server side)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    //console.log(req);
    //console.dir(req.body);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.send('thanks');
});
```

I believe that the problem lies on actually starting up my server on cloud 9 but I still get errors when doing.

You can see my attempts to stop recieving this error

```
    events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::2000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/myApp/index.js:9:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

I believe that this is what's causing get request to return the actual file contents (the actual code)

I'm also getting this error from cloud 9:

```
There are issues starting your app. Please make sure you are using the correct $IP and $PORT, run as the correct user or kill any processes that might be conflicting. You can find more information in our docs.
```

I am running the server by typing `node index.js` in the correct file directory because clicking the play button doesn't do anything. If anyone can understand what is going wrong I would greatly appreciate any help. I've tried socket.io but that doesn't solve my server-starting problems. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it. Basically for those who doesn't know cloud 9 throws this error:

```
There are issues starting your app. Please make sure you are using the correct $IP and $PORT, run as the correct user or kill any processes that might be conflicting. You can find more information in our docs.
```

This is is because cloud 9 uses an environmental variable $PORT to know which port to serve the app on. Basically to solve this issue you have to startup the server using `ionic serve -p $PORT`instead of `ionic serve` so cloud 9 will know which variable to use